# Android app frequently crashes with "android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread (ViewRootImpl.java:10750)" error

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

We were using Cordova 8 for development of the app. Recently android app crashing frequently with below crash report in firebase. We integrated firebase crashlytics. The app crashes while taking photos from camera/gallery (not every time).

> Fatal Exception:
>
> android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException
> Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
> android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread (ViewRootImpl.java:10750)

***Below are technical specifications:***

1. Cordova version 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
2. android platform - android 10.1.1

**Note:** *We can upgrade cordova version but there will be so many issues arises which we don't want as it affects the live users.*

Any plugin update required or workaround?

Comment: Have you tried Capacitor? Even Ionic developers recommend capacitor nowadays and you can integrate native apis one by one instead of a global update. But I seriously recommend to use Capacitor since it's a more updated lib.

Comment: Thanks @JoséLourenço. But how capacitor will going to help here to fix this. My project is in jquery-mobile and used cordova.

Comment: Maybe something like this: https://jsmobiledev.com/article/ionic-camera/

Comment: Its not helping me to fix that.